# Magento - Get customer group ID of the user logging in before they log in

Tags: magento

So during login, I want to check if the user is in a specific customer group and prevent login if that check fails.

I have extended the AccountController, and added in a quick check:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->loadByEmail($login['username']);
if ($customer->getGroupId() != 2) {
    $msg = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__('You must have a wholesale account to access this area.'));
    header('Location: '. Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'));
    exit;
}
```

However, running this returns session error message, "Customer website ID must be specified when using the website scope".

Basically, I just need to grab the group id of the user who is attempting to login, and I figured I could grab this through the method supplied in the customer model, loadByEmail(). But yeah, it's Friday, and apparently the MageLords want me to stay late.

I have tried a number of methods to get this working, including allowing the login, then checking the ID, then doing $session->logout() if the check fails, but this was preventing me from displaying a session error message since the logout() method is clearing all session messages (including 'core/session').

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set `website_id` before working with `loadByEmail` method. I know, it seems weird, but this is dictated by the fact, that `customer` could be a website-scoped entity. So the `loadByEmail` method will throw exception if `customer` model is not assigned to any website.

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
        ->loadByEmail($login['username']);
```

Comment: In a pure performance point of view : bad idea to do a full entity load() just to check a group id.. I would prefer a dedicated resource model sql query on customer_entity table.

Comment: nice point @Bixi; though Customer entity is one of the cheapest one to `load` (compared for example to Product), it does not contain inner objects, and personally I don't see any necessity here to use direct DB request; using your logic, we should rewrite whole Magento and get Wordpress as an endpoint

Comment: EAV entity objects are never cheap to load... And yeah, why not rewrite magento? They,re doing it already though (magento2) and started a while back (remember when sales modules tables were eav and now flat ?) In magento you should always think carefully and adapt your way of attacking DB.(load() > collection > custom query) ... or maybe you use only load() every where?

Comment: @Bixi I'm sorry, I may sounded a bit harsh :) I never said that we should always use object wrappers in Magento. Based on your task you should choose the right way yourself. However, in this particular task I don't see any necessity in using DB adapter. BTW, EAV entities are loaded the same way as Flat as long as you don't include columns from EAV tables into your selection. And yeah, denormalization of Sales tables has no connection to performance at all... Long story short, you can choose whatever option you can, just don't use chainsaw, when a knife will do

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding but are you confounding collection and object:load() ? " EAV entities are loaded the same way as Flat as long as you don't include columns from EAV tables into your selection" => that is true when using a collection. But here we're talking about the load() on an entire EAV object, and ALL of the data of a customer are loaded with a load()

Comment: you're right in one thing, I've messed up collections and models `load` :) as for the issue itself, as I said before, don't see any point in going for performance here, performance isn't always better, otherwise we would never come to OOP

Comment: Thanks for this. Pretty obvious now, but it was late on Friday when this was bugging me. For the record, Magelog($customer) in this instance logs out the object and it is rather small, so I don't think performance will be an issue (especially considering this is simply for a wholesale login which will not be used all that often).